# Flutter curved navigation bar does not switch between pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have encountered a problem which I cannot move between pages when I click on the icons, but I am setting the default page is the home page and when the application is running it only appears and I cannot move to other pages using the navigation bar.

Navigation Bar File:

```
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends  State<NavigationBar> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  final Search _search = Search();
  final UserNoti _userNoti = UserNoti();
  final HomePage _homePage = HomePage();
  final MyProfile _myProfile = MyProfile();
  final MyMajor _mymajor = MyMajor();

 Widget _showPage =  new HomePage();

 Widget _pageChooser(int page)
    {
        switch (page)
        {
          case 0:
            return _search;
            break;

          case 1:
            return _userNoti;
            break;

          case 2:
            return _homePage;
            break;

          case 3:
            return _myProfile;
            break;

          case 4:
            return _mymajor;
            break;

          default:
            return _homePage;
        }
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.purple]),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 25.0, // soften the shadow
                spreadRadius: -10.0, //extend the shadow
              )
            ],
          ),
          child: CurvedNavigationBar(
            index: 2,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
            buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.6),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            animationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
            items: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.search, size: 32, color: Colors.white,),
              Icon(Icons.notifications_active, size: 32, color: Colors.white,),
              Icon(Icons.home, size: 40, color: Colors.white,),
              Icon(Icons.chat, size: 32, color: Colors.white,),
              Icon(Icons.school, size: 32, color: Colors.white,),
            ],
          onTap: (int tappedPage){
              _showPage = _pageChooser(tappedPage);
          },),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: _showPage,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Now I will put one code for one of those pages for example User Notification Page:

```
class UserNoti extends StatefulWidget {
  final String myuid,majname,uniname;
  UserNoti({Key key, this.myuid,this.majname,this.uniname}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserNotiState createState() => _UserNotiState();
}

class _UserNotiState extends  State<UserNoti> {
  String myapplang = null;
  var my_uid;
  var myDoc;

  bool loading = false;


  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    checkLang();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? LoadingMain()
        : Directionality(
            textDirection: myapplang == 'ar' ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                  appBar: GradientAppBar(
                    backgroundColorStart: Colors.deepPurple,
                    backgroundColorEnd: Colors.purple,
                    title: Text(
                      myapplang == 'ar' ? "الإشعارات" : "Notifications" ,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily:  myapplang == 'ar' ? 'Tajawal' : 'BalooDa2' ),),
                  ),
                  body: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(myDoc).collection('Notifications').orderBy('date',descending: true).snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                                    if(!snapshot.hasData)
                                    {
                                      const Text('Loading...');
                                    }

                                    else{
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index)
                                          {
                                            DocumentSnapshot mypost = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                                            return Stack(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                FadeAnimation(0.2,Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(15.0),color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 75, 96, .9),
                                                        boxShadow: [
                                                          BoxShadow(
                                                            color: Colors.black,
                                                            blurRadius: 30.0, // soften the shadow
                                                            spreadRadius: -25.0, //extend the shadow
                                                          )
                                                        ],),
                                                      child:InkWell(
                                                        onTap: () {
                                                          // setState(() => loading = true);
                                                          if(mypost['type'] == 'comment'){
                                                            if(mypost['location'] == 'Majors'){

                                                              Firestore.instance
                                                                  .document('/Majors/${widget.majname}/Posts/${mypost['pdoc']}')
                                                                  .get()
                                                                  .then((val) {

                                                                if(val.data['pid'] != null && val.data['text'] != null  && val.data['uid'] != null && val.data['uimg'] != null && val.data['uname'] != null && val.data['uname'] != null)
                                                                {
                                                                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Comments(pid: val.data['pid'], text: val.data['text'],img: val.data['img'],uid: val.data['uid'], uimg: val.data['uimg'],uname: val.data['uname'],majname: widget.majname,pdoc:mypost['pdoc'] )));

                                                                }

                                                                else {
                                                                  showWraning(context,myapplang == 'ar' ? "حدثت مشكلة، قد يكون الإشعار محذوف أو مشكلة بالإنترنت، حاول لاحقًا." : "There is a problem, maybe notification has been deleted or problem with internet connection, try again later.");
                                                                }

                                                                /*

                                                           */
                                                              }).catchError((e) {
                                                                print(e);
                                                              });

                                                            }

                                                            else {

                                                              Firestore.instance
                                                                  .document('/Universities/${widget.uniname}/Posts/${mypost['pdoc']}')
                                                                  .get()
                                                                  .then((val) {

                                                                if(val.data['pid'] != null && val.data['text'] != null  && val.data['uid'] != null && val.data['uimg'] != null && val.data['uname'] != null && val.data['uname'] != null)
                                                                {
                                                                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new U_Comments(pid: val.data['pid'], text: val.data['text'],img: val.data['img'],uid: val.data['uid'], uimg: val.data['uimg'],uname: val.data['uname'],uniname: widget.uniname,pdoc:mypost['pdoc'] )));

                                                                }

                                                                else {
                                                                  showWraning(context,myapplang == 'ar' ? "حدثت مشكلة، قد يكون الإشعار محذوف أو مشكلة بالإنترنت، حاول لاحقًا." : "There is a problem, maybe notification has been deleted or problem with internet connection, try again later.");

                                                                }

                                                                /*

                                                           */
                                                              }).catchError((e) {
                                                                print(e);
                                                              });

                                                            }
                                                          }

                                                          else {
                                                            print('not comment!');
                                                          }
                                                        },
                                                        child: ListTile(
                                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                                                            leading: ClipRRect(
                                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                                                              child: Icon(Icons.insert_comment,color: Colors.deepPurple,size: 40,),
                                                            ),
                                                            title: Column(
                                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                                Text(
                                                                  "${mypost['text']}",
                                                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'BalooDa2'),
                                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                                ),
                                                                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            // subtitle: Text("Intermediate", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                                            trailing:
                                                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0)),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                                                  ],
                                                ),),
                                              ],
                                            );

                                          }

                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 0.0,
                                      width: 0.0,
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
    );
  }
```

I removed a few codes that had no need.
Note when running the application the active page is Homepage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are setting your _showPage variable with a new page, but not in a way that will force your app to re-render the widget tree. Try using SetState in your tap function to do this.

```
onTap: (int tappedPage){
    setState(() {
      _showPage = _pageChooser(tappedPage);
    });
}),
```